# Gulp 4. The problem with browser-sync // The following tasks did not complete: browser-sync

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

Do not understand what the error read documentation in browser-sync where gulp 4 there is really nothing written about it. In the documentation of gulp 4 also did not understand( async ). How to resolve this problem. Thanks.
 *bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla*

```
 'default' errored after 23 ms
 The following tasks did not complete: browser-sync
 Did you forget to signal async completion?

var gulp        = require('gulp'),
      gutil         = require('gulp-util' ),
      sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
      browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
      concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
      cleancss      = require('gulp-clean-css'),
      rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
      autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      notify        = require('gulp-notify');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
        notify: false,
        // open: false,
        // online: false, // Work Offline Without Internet Connection
        // tunnel: true, tunnel: "projectname", // Demonstration page: http://projectname.localtunnel.me
    })
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/'+syntax+'/**/*.'+syntax+'')
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on("error", notify.onError()))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min', prefix : '' }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
    .pipe(cleancss( {level: { 1: { specialComments: 0 } } }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'app/js/common.js',
        ])
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

gulp.task('code', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});


    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch('app/'+syntax+'/**/*.'+syntax+'', gulp.parallel('styles'));
        gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], gulp.parallel('scripts'));
        gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.parallel('code'))
    });
    gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'browser-sync'));
```

Comment: is there a reason you do it different then in the browser-sync docs ?  https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp you have no create or init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
        notify: false,
        // open: false,
        // online: false, // Work Offline Without Internet Connection
        // tunnel: true, tunnel: "projectname", // Demonstration page: http://projectname.localtunnel.me
    });
    done();
});
```

Note the `done`'s - that is an easy way to indicate task completion for a browser-sync set-up.  See [callback to signal async completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback).

---

For @Dirk's comment about not using `.create()` see

> Post 2.0.0 syntax (recommended)
>
> Whilst the above is still supported [ed. no create()], we now recommend the following
>   instead. Calling .create() means you get a unique reference & allows
>   you to create multiple servers or proxies.

From [api documentation](https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-init).

So using create allows to open multiple instances of browserSync - serving different files or watching/reloading different files - but is not necessary in simpler cases.